# Xcode in release mode fails to compile <immintrin.h> - complains about __builtin_ia32_emms()

Tags: c++, xcode, x86-64, simd, intrinsics

I'm very new to Xcode, and developing SIMD(SSE/AVX) codes for macOS with Xcode 12.4 (12D4e) on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.
This very simple code can be compiled in Debug scheme:

```c
#include <immintrin.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

But in Release Scheme, the header makes error: "**Too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0**" for this line of "mmintrin.h".

```
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
```

What can I do to compile it in Release scheme?

Comment: That's weird; the `emms` instruction doesn't take any operands, and GCC's definition of `_mm_empty()` does use `__builtin_ia32_emms()` with no args like you'd expect.  So does the mainline (not Apple) clang 11.0 version of `mmintrin.h` on my Linux desktop.    IDK why clang would expect 2 args.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same settings for e.g. `CLANG_X86_VECTOR_INSTRUCTIONS` for both debug and release builds?

Comment: @PaulR: MMX is baseline for x86-64, and this error seems to be about a `__builtin` function, *not* an intrinsic that's only conditionally defined by a header.  (Such builtins will report failure to inline because of target-specific options if you e.g. used `-mno-mmx`, but I don't think that could explain expecting this builtin to take 2 args.)  Of course, I don't use MacOS or Xcode, so I can't rule out the possibility of a problem like that producing these symptoms, but it seems highly unlikely.  (Not that anything else makes any sense either, if that error message is being quoted correctly.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, I know it doesn’t make sense, but I had a similar weird problem with an Xcode project recently. I can’t remember the details or the fix unfortunately, but I remember there was some discrepancy between the debug and release build settings.

Comment: One other thing to check: make sure your release build is not multi-architecture (x86 and Apple Silicon) - I think Xcode 12 defaults to this for release builds on new projects. Make sure it’s x86 only.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I could compile it when I set the "Architectures" for Release as `x86_64`! (But I wonder why it is succeede  in Debug scheme even it's architectures setting is `Standard Architectures (Appple Silicon, Intel)`.)

Comment: Yes, I think this was the same problem I had when I upgraded to Xcode 12 - the Debug build defaults to the current architecture only, but the Release build tries to build a "fat" binary with both x86 and ARM code, so if you have any x86-specific code (such as Intel intrinsics) then it fails on the ARM part of the build. Unfortunately the resulting error message is misleading so it's not obvious what the problem is at first sight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any Intel-specific code (such as Intel intrinsics) then you need to make sure that your Release build is set for x86-64 architecture only. In Xcode 12 the default is to build for both x86-64 and Apple Silicon in the Release build, which results in spurious error messages when Intel intrinsics are encountered in the Apple Silicon part of the build.

Comment: Ah, that makes some sense.  And as you said in a comment, the default in a Debug build is only the current architecture.  Still doesn't explain why it might think `__builtin_ia32_emms()` should take 2 args when targeting ARM, though!  Hopefully a future version of xcode will put some kind of `#if` / `#error` in immintrin.h to just tell you that you're including it when not targeting x86-64 or i386.

Comment: Yes, I assume this only impacts a relatively small subset of developers who have x86-specific code in their project and start a new project under Xcode 12 (old projects should be fine). The error message is bizarre though.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Your description was clear and my question was resolved.
I found that `#ifdef __x86_64__` enables writing both x86_64 code and Apple Sillicon code in the same time (even for Release Scheme with Standard Architectures (Appple Silicon, Intel)).